# C++ Auto Generate different named functions using __COUNTER__

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor, googletest

I want to generate different named function useful for writing unit test cases. I want to do this basically to give unique name to each unit test case.

I am using *google test framework* for writing unit test cases. 
I have to use `TEST_Macro` to write unit test cases. I want to automatically give incrementing numbers to every unit test.

Here is my (non-working) code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define join(x, y) x## y

void join(test, __COUNTER__)()
{
    cout << "\n 1";
}

void join(test, __COUNTER__)()
{
    cout << "\n 2";
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;

     test0() ;
     test1() ;

    return 0;
}
```

What is the correct way to generate unique function names using `__COUNTER__`?

Comment: Could you describe in which way it is not working?

Comment: Presumably the task of writing the actual test is a lot more than just numbering it, so I'd just do it by hand. That way you can give numbers some meaning, e.g. 1xxxxxx is basic stuff, ..., 9xxxxxx is miscelanous; 13xxxxx is string handling, 15xxxxx memory management, and so on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So this is the old "paste happens before evaluation of macro arguments", so you get test__COUNTER__ instead of test0.

You need to do a nested macro:

```
#define expandedjoin(x,y) x##y
#define join(x, y) expandedjoin(x, y)
```

(The rest of your code gives lots of errors because you are passing a `void` function to `cout`, which isn't good)

Complete working code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define expandedjoin(x,y) x##y
#define join(x, y) expandedjoin(x, y)

void join(test, __COUNTER__)()
{
    cout << "\n 1";
}

void join(test, __COUNTER__)()
{
    cout << "\n 2";
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;

    test0();
    test1();

    return 0;
}
```